# ImageMagick - convert different results on two different servers

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using the below command in order to generate a coupon image. In my dev environment I'm using Ubuntu Server and in production I'm using Centos 7.

```
convert 
-font /some-path/Gotham-Ultra.ttf 
-gravity center 
-geometry +0-0 
-background none 
-gravity south 
-fill #FC3B45 
-size 330x90 
caption:VIERNES 
-font Helvetica-Bold 
-gravity north 
-background none 
-pointsize 25 
-fill #671646 
-size 330x 
caption:–––––––––––––––––––– 
-font /some-path/Gotham-Ultra.ttf 
-gravity center 
-background none 
-fill #671646 
-size 330x210 
+pointsize 
caption:4 EMPANADAS 2 PORCIONES DE ENSALADAS 2 REFRESCOS DE 355ML POR $195 
-font Helvetica-Bold 
-gravity north 
-background none 
-pointsize 25 
-fill #671646 
-size 330x 
caption:–––––––––––––––––––– 
-append /some-path/canvas/yellow.png 
+swap 
-gravity center 
-composite /some-path/photo.jpg 
-crop 450x480+0+0 
+swap 
-append 
/tmp/coupon_image20180212-7979-p52o3f.jpg
```

So, I expect that the caption will resize the font automatically based on the space given as per: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption_bestfit

This is my output in my prod env:

**Centos 7 (Production)**

[image]

And I expect the following:

**Ubuntu Server (Dev)**

[image]

The only difference for now is the ImageMagick version:

**Prod:**

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-16 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

**Dev:**

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2016-06-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

What do you recommend guys? Should I match the versions? (downgrade in production)
Is there other options available?

Comment: It is strange the caption:VIERNES is working in both cases and the other one dose not. I would try a test just creating your problem caption on a blank image also another test wrapping the problem caption in " "

Comment: Caption has been tweaked over time and versions. So it is possible that there has been changes. Also I note that you supply the width only and pointsize for most of your captions, but in the one that changes, you have left off the pointsize (+pointsize) and provided a widthxheight. Perhaps you should do them all the same with width only and pointsize. Also check that your version of freetype is the same. 6.7.8.9 looks like it may be the bad one to me. Try creating the two captions for text first before setting the pointsize and reorder the way you combine them in the output

Comment: Can you also provide the input images you are using, so others can test your code?

Comment: @fmw42 , thanks for the comments guys. Here are the images I'm using: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10dgCkYqBwG3gtXWRTbqCTmLrnzDqPZdR

Comment: How can I check the FreeType versions used in Image Magick? @fmw42

Comment: @fmw42, a fixed pointsize is not an option right now... the text is defined by a user form so it's hard to determine a right pointsize. That's why I needed the caption best fit option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some problems as listed above. On Unix, you need end of line `\`. You have listed the photo.jpg but provided img.jpg. You used -append at the end, but it should be +append. On Unix, you must put quotes about your label text and about hex colors. So the proper listing for your code is as follows. Change the paths to your files and names and path to your fonts as desired.

```
convert \
-font /Library/fonts/Gotham-Ultra.ttf \
-gravity center \
-geometry +0-0 \
-background none \
-gravity south \
-fill "#FC3B45" \
-size 330x90 \
caption:VIERNES \
-font /Library/fonts/Helvetica-Bold.ttf \
-gravity north \
-background none \
-pointsize 25 \
-fill "#671646" \
-size 330x \
caption:"––––––––––––––––––––" \
-font /Library/fonts/Gotham-Ultra.ttf \
-gravity center \
-background none \
-fill "#671646" \
-size 330x210 \
+pointsize \
caption:"4 EMPANADAS 2 PORCIONES DE ENSALADAS 2 REFRESCOS DE 355ML POR $195" \
-font /Library/fonts/Helvetica-Bold.ttf \
-gravity north \
-background none \
-pointsize 25 \
-fill "#671646" \
-size 330x \
caption:"––––––––––––––––––––" \
-append \
yellow.png \
+swap \
-gravity center \
-composite \
photo.jpg \
-crop 450x480+0+0 \
+repage \
+swap \
+append \
coupon_image20180212-7979-p52o3f.jpg
```

Where I have put the images in the same directory location as running the command line. I have also added +repage after the crop.

Nevertheless, IM 6.7.8.9 is buggy. I can reproduce your bad results for that version. I get the proper results for IM 6.9.9.34 Q16 MacOS Sierra, the current version and for IM 6.7.7.10 and IM 6.8.6.8 (the next version I had handy). IM 6.7.8.9 has proven to me to be buggy in a number of ways. It was a poor choice for the Linux distros, in my opinion. You should look into an upgrade if possible.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to upgrade tomorrow and see if that fixes the issue. I will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: I installed ImageMagick 6.9.9 with and my issue has gone! Please see: https://serverfault.com/questions/897151/centos-7-upgrade-imagemagick for upgrade instructions in Centos7